# python re(regular expression) replace all occurrence of a pattern but exclude a scenario

Tags: python, regex

I have a tricky scenario to use regular expression in Python.

Here is the example--

Input:

```
text = """4056,"Wholesale, Operations","Performed some ""activities"", at 10 am. ",19/12/2022,,"a,B" """
```

The Output expecting is:

```
4056,DUMMY,DUMMY,19/12/2022,,DUMMY
```

Basically I want to replace everything in the `" "` to `DUMMY`. However, I'd like to escape text wrapped by `"" ""`. As you can see from the example, `"Performed some ""activities"", at 10 am. "` should be replaced as a whole.

Any tips? Much appreciated!

Comment: You could try something like [`"(?:"".*?""|[^"])*"`](https://regex101.com/r/Izz2XK/1)

Comment: That looks like CSV. Can you use the built-in [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) or [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)?

Comment: @HaoWu That won't match `"fo""o"`; drop `.*?""`: `"(?:[^"]|"")*"`.

Comment: @InSync You're right, I was assuming the quote must be enclosed, [`"(?:[^"]|"")*"`](https://regex101.com/r/Izz2XK/latest) should work just fine

Comment: That worked, Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by define a pattern and replace the pattern with dummies.

```
import re

text = """4056,"Wholesale, Operations","Performed some ""activities"", at 10 am. ",19/12/2022,,"a,B" """
pattern = r'(".*?(?:""|[^"])*")'
def replace_match(match):
    return 'DUMMY'
result = re.sub(pattern, replace_match, text)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
4056,DUMMY,DUMMY,19/12/2022,,DUMMY
```